# how to chroot /var/ftp directory

Tags: shell, centos, chroot

I have tried to **chroot** /var/ftp in CentOS 6.6.

I have followed the below steps to chroot /var/ftp

```
useradd -d /var/ftp -s /sbin/nologin pica
```

Modified **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** as

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User pica
ChrootDirectory /var/ftp/
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

after performing the same. I have able to access sftp pica@X.X.X.X.

But unable to use ls/put/get or any commands, it says

```
sftp> put Sim.zip
Uploading Sim.zip to /Sim.zip
Couldn't get handle: Permission denied
```

Output of ls-ld for /var/ftp

```
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Aug 21 18:19
```

Note: it works fine for me when i use any folder derived from /usr/* directory instead of /var/ftp

Can any one help me how to solve this permission problem?

Thanks,

Pica

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It blocked sftp login too.

Comment: looks like you need to create an extra dir /var/ftp/pica owned by pica and set the home dir of user pica to / (with /var/ftp belonging to root).

Comment: Thanks, But my intention is to use the /var/ftp folder only. Any other way to solve the permission issue?

Comment: ssh insists that the whole path given by ChrootDirectory is owned by root and not writeable group nor others.  Your best bet is to use a ChrootDirectory of /var/realsftp, owned by root, add a subdir pica owned by pica, set the home of user pica to /pica, and use a symbolic link from /var/sftp to /var/realsftp/pica/.